# how to validate modelstate in async controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, controller, modelstate

I am trying to use Async controller and am not able to figure out how would one validate the user input.

Following are the two async methods defined in my controller.  Should I check for ModelState.IsValid in the SearchAsync method or SearchCompleted method.  If SearchAsync then how will return the view result as its return type is void.  If SearchCompleted then how will the method know about searchForm parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public void SearchAsync(BusinessSearchForm searchForm)
{
    AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        var suggestions = _searchSvc.GetSuggestions(searchForm.BusinessName, searchForm.StreetAddress, searchForm.City, searchForm.PostalCode);
        AsyncManager.Parameters["suggestions"] = suggestions;                   
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
    }).Start();
}

public ActionResult SearchCompleted(IEnumerable<BusinessSuggestionBase> suggestions)
{
    return View(suggestions);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work for me.  I end up checking for modelstate in both methods.  Added the initial model as a param to the completed method.  Asp.net Mvc seemed to persist the modelstate between the two methods

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public void SearchAsync(BusinessSearchForm searchForm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var suggestions = _searchBusinessSvc.GetSuggestions(searchForm.BusinessName, searchForm.StreetAddress, searchForm.City, searchForm.PostalCode);
                    AsyncManager.Parameters["suggestions"] = suggestions;
                }
                AsyncManager.Parameters["searchForm"] = searchForm;
                AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
            }).Start();             
        }
    }

    public ActionResult SearchCompleted(BusinessSearchForm searchForm,IEnumerable<BusinessSuggestionBase> suggestions)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TempData["suggestions"] = suggestions;
            return RedirectToAction("SearchResult");
        }
        return View(searchForm);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
AsyncManager.Parameters['ModelIsValid'] = false;
```

in the Async method, and

```
if(AsyncManager.Parameters['ModelIsValid'] == false) { ... }
```

in the Completed method to check and see if there was a validation issue. Simply do not increment the outstanding operations, and do not perform any further logic. The Completed method will fire, and you can check the the value.

Comment: I had come up with the answer that I posted earlier though stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to enter it within 24hrs.  Your answer is pretty close to what I had so will give you the credit for it. You mentioned not increment the outstanding operations. Does that make a difference?

Comment: The Completed method wont execute until the outstanding operations are completed, aka = 0. Thus, if you never increment, you will never need to decrement, and therefore the outstanding operations remain at 0. This allows the Completed method to execute. Doesn't matter, so long as there are no outstanding operations.

Comment: Thanks xixonia.  Updated my answer with this in consideration